# jQuery nav-tab onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my Django template, I have several nav-tabs that are populated by the context variable:

```
<div class="content-object">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="object_tab" role="tablist">
      {% for object in object_list %}
        {% if object == object_list.0 %}
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="{% url 'object_contents' %}?object={{object}}" class="nav-link" data-target="#chartdiv" role="tab"
            aria-selected="true">
              {{object}}
            </a>
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{% url 'object_contents' %}?object={{object}}" class="nav-link" data-target="#chartdiv" role="tab"
            aria-selected="true">
              {{object}}
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the above code, I am setting the first list nav-item as active i.e it gets highlighted in blue color.

However, when I click on any other nav-tab, its class becomes 'active' and **the other tab gets highlighted but it does not execute the href link associated with it.**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
      $('.nav-tabs > li > a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var actived_nav = $('.nav-tabs > li.active');
        actived_nav.removeClass('active');
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
       }); 
   });
</script>
```

I am unsure why its `href` click does not execute.

Also, here is my css styling for the ul, li:

```
.object-domain > .nav-tabs > li > a,   
.object-domain > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.object-domain > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover{
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.object-domain ul > li.active > a{
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `event.preventDefault()`. If you click on the `a`, then its default action will be prevented. Removing this line will solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.nav-tabs > li > a').click(function(event){
        var actived_nav = $('.nav-tabs > li.active');
        actived_nav.removeClass('active');
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
        window.location.href = event.target;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I removed that line, what happens is that the href does get executed for the selected nav-tab, but the highlighted blue color still remains on the first nav-tab, and the newly selected nav-tab does not get highlighted (does not turn blue)

Comment: Maybe add a `window.location` modification? I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a **if** condition to your **li** tag. I dont know django please forgive me for any syntax related mistake. There are no use of onclick on **anchor** tag because you want to redirect to a given url when click to link.

```
<div class="content-object">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="object_tab" role="tablist">
  {% for object in object_list %}
    <li class="nav-item {% if object == request.GET.get('object') %} active {% endif %} ">
        <a href="{% url 'object_contents' %}?object={{object}}" class="nav-link" data-target="#chartdiv" role="tab"
        aria-selected="true">
          {{object}}
        </a>
      </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```